# What's the name of this maneuver for unlimited delta-v?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, delta-v, terminology

Let's say you have magical unlimited delta-v, but very low thrust-to-weight ratio. You could travel by accelerating constantly for half the trip, then braking for the other half, until your arrival.

I remember someone describing this maneuver and using a name, but I can't remember the name or find any references. What is it called?

Comment: What you're talking about sounds a lot like an interstellar solar sail. Is that it, or are you using a conventional propulsion method?

Comment: Well... it could be a solar sail. The propulsion method is irrelevant. What matters is that delta-v is unlimited or practically unlimited.

Comment: In that case, @RussellBorogove's answer is definitely the right one. Good question.

Comment: Imagine the constant acceleration to be 1g. No more worries about artificial gravity!

Comment: @SF: a 1g constant acceleration and almost endless delta-v sounds wonderful, until you realize that the antimatter fuel needed for this means basically everyone can own a nuke.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a [brachistochrone](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/torchships.php) or constant-acceleration trajectory; Heinlein was fond of it and called the turnover the "skew-flip maneuver".

Comment: That's it! That name is hard to remember. Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the "skew-flip maneuver" was a curved path designed to maintain a constant 1-G on-board acceleration during turnover. A simpler alternative would be to turn off the engines, rotate the ship, and restart the engines. Reasons for the skew-flip might include the comfort of the passengers and concern about being able to restart the engines.

Comment: See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrachistochroneProblem.html

for another origin for the weird word...

Comment: Heinlein called it a Skew Flip Turnover: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_flip_turnover